# JavaScript - Nested FOR loop executing twice

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a nested FOR loop that iterates over an object, and updating variables or attributes based on conditions. The last 'IF' on this loop formats a date and updates the field accordingly. For some reason the final line causes the loop to iterate twice, therefore updating the 'formattedDate' variable twice (in the object, there is only one single element with the 'childTag' = 'date'. Any help is appreciated!

```
for (let i = 0; i < submitFormData.tabs.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < submitFormData.tabs[i].elements.length; j++) {
    if (submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].childTag == "project_name") {
      projectName = submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].value;
    } else if (submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].childTag == "location_store") {
      locationStore = ' #' + submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].value;
    } else if (submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].childTag == "location_street") {
      locationStreet = submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].value;
    } else if (submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].childTag == "location_city") {
      locationCity = submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].value;
    } else if (submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].childTag == "location_state") {
      locationState = submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].value;
    } else if (submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].childTag == "location_zip") {
      locationZip = submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].value;
    } else if (submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].childTag == "date") {
      if (submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].value != "") {
        console.log(submitFormData)
        date = (submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].value.substring(0, 10));
        formattedDate = (date.substring(5, 11) + '-' + date.substring(0, 4));
        console.log(formattedDate, 'formatted date')
        submitFormData.tabs[i].elements[j].value = formattedDate;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample of Object
[image]

Comment: We can't really help you without a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: I recommend you learn to use `forEach()` so you don't have to keep writing out those long, nested array expressions.

Comment: Can you add sample data?

Comment: Yes, added to original post

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the loop you manipulate the list which you iterate over.

```
submitFormData.tabs[i].elements
```

It would be better to make a copy of it and iterate over it.

```
const newSubmitFormData = [...submitFormData.tabs[i].elements]

for (let j = 0; j < newSubmitFormData .length; j++) { /* your code */ }
```

Comment: While there are certainly times when this could cause a problem, I don't see how it could be causing this specific problem.

Comment: This is an array of objects, and he's modifying the objects. You're making a shallow copy, so the copy will have references to the same objects and the assignments will affect it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's my fault.